# Maximize ratio of quadratic form!

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I should maximize kind of quadratic ratio, 
$$\max_{x \in R^k, x \neq 0} \frac{(x^ta)^2}{x^t x} $$
,where $a$ is a $k$ by 1 constant vector.

Because $x$ is not a scalar, but a vector, I cannot apply the method using derivative. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Since both the numerator and denominator are scalars, more specifically scalar functions of $x$, the standard quotient rule applies to determine the derivative. However, to compute the derivative of the numerator and denominator, you may need https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus to set up the system of equations to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), we get
$$
(x^ta)^2 = \langle x,a\rangle ^2 \leq \|x\|^2\|a\|^2 =  x^tx\;a^ta
$$
and 
$(x^ta)^2 = x^tx\,a^ta$ if and only if $x$ and $a$ are linearly dependent.

So your solution is $x=\lambda a$ for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and the actual maximum is $a^t a.$

Comment: Thank you so much~